# How to find lines using patterns in a file in UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, awk, grep

I am trying to use a .txt file with around 5000 patterns (spaced with a line) to search through another file of 18000 lines for any matches. So far I've tried every form of grep and awk I can find on the internet and it's still not working, so I am completely stumped.

Here's some text from each file.

Pattern.txt

```html
rs2622590
rs925489
rs2798334
rs6801957
rs6801957
rs13137008
rs3807989
rs10850409
rs2798269
rs549182
```

There's no extra spaces or anything.

File.txt

```html
snpid hg18chr bp a1 a2 zscore pval CEUmaf
rs3131972       1       742584  A       G       0.289   0.7726  .
rs3131969       1       744045  A       G       0.393   0.6946  .
rs3131967       1       744197  T       C       0.443   0.658   .
rs1048488       1       750775  T       C       -0.289  0.7726  .
rs12562034      1       758311  A       G       -1.552  0.1207  0.09167
rs4040617       1       769185  A       G       -0.414  0.6786  0.875
rs4970383       1       828418  A       C       0.214   0.8303  .
rs4475691       1       836671  T       C       -0.604  0.5461  .
rs1806509       1       843817  A       C       -0.262  0.7933  .
```

The file.txt was downloaded directly from a med directory.

I'm pretty new to UNIX so any help would be amazing!

Sorry edit: I have definitely tried every single thing you guys are recommending and the result is blank. Am I maybe missing a syntax issue or something in my text files?

P.P.S I know there are matches as doing individual greps works. I'll move this question to unix.stackexchange. Thanks for your answers guys I'll try them all out.

Issue solved: I was obviously using DOS carriages. I didn't know about this before so thank you everyone that answered. For future users who are having this issue, here is the solution that worked:

dos2unix *

awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0];next} $1 in p' Patterns.txt File.txt > Output.txt

Comment: Google "grep patterns from file" comes back with loads of answers. But obviously "every form of grep" didn't include `grep -f` : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83260/reading-grep-patterns-from-a-file

Comment: Better suited to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: If your pattern file contains DOS carriage returns (and the target file obviously doesn't, at least in the same places) there will be no matches.  Search fro the hundreds (or possibly thousands) of questions where the answer is `dos2unix`.  The [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) also has a discussion.

Comment: Do not use the word `pattern` as it is ambiguous. Your file contains strings. Do you want to use them to do a string or regular expression comparison or something else? If regular expressions do you want BREs or EREs or something else? Do you want a partial match or a full match? Do you want to match on a particular field or the whole line or something else?

Comment: @John3136 why would you suggest this is better suited for a different forum? It's a trivial text manipulation question, we just need a bit more information from the OP on what the problem is before we can help them solve it.

Comment: @EdMorton It's not really a programming question. OP is looking for tools to do a particular task, not looking to write some code. His line `I'm pretty new to UNIX so any help would be amazing!` also hints he knows it is more UNIX tool related than programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idk if it's what you want or not, but this will print every line from File.txt whose first field equals a string from Patterns.txt:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0];next} $1 in p' Patterns.txt File.txt
```

If that is not what you want, tell us what you do want. If it is what you want but doesn't produce the output you expect then one or both of your files contains control characters courtesy of being created in Windows so run `dos2unix` or similar on them both first.

Comment: Thanks Ed, worked perfectly. I ran dos2unix on every single file and ran your awks code. Came up with all the matches and I'm now piping it into another file.


dos2unix *


awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0];next} $1 in p' Patterns.txt File.txt | Output.txt

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep -Fw` here:

```
grep -Fw -f Pattern.txt File.txt
```

**Options used are:**

- `-F` - Fixed string search to tread input as non-regex
- `-w` - Match full words only
- `-f file` - Read pattern from a file

Comment: That's OK but will match on any part of each line of File.txt when they appear to only want to match on the first field so there's a chance it will produce a false match.

Comment: Agreed, I would use an awk one liner for matching only first field though was waiting for OP to leave some comments to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

Use a shell script to read each line of the file containing your patterns then fgrep it.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$1

awk '{kount++;print   $0}' $FILENAME | fgrep -f - PATTERNFILE.txt
```

Comment: What do you think your awk script is doing that `cat $FILENAME` wouldn't do? Whats the point of the pipe at all?